# Adobe AIR Client Side Session

Tags: adobe, air

I can't help but feel I'm missing some simple, critical piece of information.

**Is there some way to store application level (session) data to survive across page loads?**

I'm building a stand alone application that has multiple web pages,
every time I load a new page with a normal link -

i.e. `<a href="newpage.html">Next Step</a>`

The *ENTIRE* runtime environment gets reset when the user clicks that link.  I tried using the `localSystemOBject` in flash, but that treats each page as part of a separate domain, meaning *every page gets its own local store*, and again, **no data is shared**.  Is there a way to tell AIR that they are part of the same domain?

Basically in a normal web-app this is handled on the server side (php) but I don't 
have a server or php, and I really don't want to completely restructure this thing into one monster web page.  I just want to replace the existing Ajax calls with local reads and writes from a sqlite database -- however, every time the user moves to a new page (for the next step in the process) ALL the session data is LOST.

Help?  Ideas?  Suggestions?  Do I have to write my own session manager?
I can't believe I'm the first person to run into this.  I think I'm just forming the question badly for google / stackoverflow search. (I hope)

Comment: Can you describe your project? Is this an HTML-based air app, or a Flash-based app using HTML views, or content you're viewing in a browser?

Comment: Yes, it is a desk top application written using JavaScript with jQuery, and HTML.  I'm developing using Aptana Studio 2.0.  There is no Flash, no Browser.  Just Adobe Air's built in Webkit browser.